# Error installing deps on swanky phala

Tags: ink, phala

I'm having issues initiating my swanky phala project. I keep getting this error below. [image]

Is there anything i'm missing?

update: I went to the tests directory to run `npm install` and I got these errors.

[image]

how do i fix these deps conflict?

Answer (score 1):

It seems everything went through except for NodeJs dependencies.
If you `cd` into your `test-swanky-phala` directory and run `yarn` or `npm install` manually, it should show the reason for failing.
Without more info, it's probably NodeJs version or something similar.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response! 
I'm editing the question to show the errors i got

Comment: It seems like those are peer dependencies, meaning you should install them into your project manually.